# GWT: Get URL of file located on server

Tags: file, gwt, download

I am developing an web application which can upload/download a file from client to PostgreSQL database server via GWT RPC call.

I managed to create an upload servlet which store desired file(choosed by user via FileUpload widget) to Glassfish "TEMP" directory => then i used SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('"+name+"',lo_import('"+f.getCanonicalPath()+"\\TEMP\\"+name+"'),...)
```

which put that file into database. This works pretty good.

Problem occurs when i want to download file from server to client. First i need to put the file back to TEMP dir with SQL command lo_export(...) -> this didn't work (some ERROR when creating a server file, permission denied), so i put the file manually to TEMP dir.

Question is how can i display that file which is stored on server in TEMP dir?

- my path to glassfish server temp dir:C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-3.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\TEMP\example.pdf
- when deploying app url looks like: `http://localhost:8080/AppName/`
- i tried something like that: Window.open("http://localhost:8080/AppName/TEMP/example.pdf", "_blank", "enabled")

My CODE:
Client side:

```
String link = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "filedownloadservlet";
Window.open(link,event.getSelectedItem().getText(),"enabled");
```

so i pass to servlet located on server side a link and a file name...am i right ?

Server side:

```
public class FileDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String path = "TEMP//"; // Your absolute path
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {             

    String filename = req.getParameter("filename");
    System.out.println(filename); // THIS IS NULL value

    File userManualFile = new File(path + filename);
    // You can fetch a Blob from the database instead.

    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    resp.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=skuska.pdf");

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(userManualFile);

    IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, servletOutputStream);
    servletOutputStream.flush();
```

When i press a file in Tree widget it shows me a new browser window with this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: TEMP\null (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot download a file with a RPC call. You must use a normal java servlet. You have to write the bytes into the HttpServletResponse. You can get the bytes from the file in the database by doing an SQL query.

This example is done with spring MVC.

```
@Controller
public class UserManualServlet {

  private String path = "..." // Your absolute path

  @RequestMapping("/app/usermanual.download")
  public void generateInterceptActivationDeactivationReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException
  {

    String filename = request.getParameter("filename");

    File userManualFile = new File(path + filename);
    // You can fetch a Blob from the database instead.

    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"user-manual.pdf\"");

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(userManualFile);

    IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream, servletOutputStream);
    servletOutputStream.flush();
}
```

In this example, you can call the URL : ../app/usermanual.download?filename=usermanual.pdf to download the file.

Comment: i tried something similar like u did, but when using Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "filedownloadservlet";) in client side how i pass to server the filename of file i want to open/donwload ? I have a clicklistner on treeitems in Tree widget which represents files located on server side inTEMP dir...when i clicked the item a want to open a ne window or save as dialog which helps me download/open that desired pdf file...Because in your example your filename is set as static value user-manual.pdf ...I am not sure if you see with what i have a big problem to understand how it works -@SimonLG

Comment: You can pass it as a HTTP GET parameter in the URL. I changed by code to show you how to pass on the client side and get the value on the server side.

Comment: please check one more time my code at the top of the page (in my original question), thanks @Simon LG

Comment: I don't see where you pass your GET parameter in the your URL. You must call the following URL : GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "filedownloadservlet" + "?yourDynamicFilename"

Comment: right, i corrected this one, so i have another error but a new one :) It's HTTP 404 : java.io.FileNotFoundException: TEMP\null (The system cannot find the file specified)...sorry i bother you so much - @Simon LG

Comment: 404 means that the page is not found. I cannot help you with that.

Comment: OK so i played with it a little bit longer and it's working now :) you saved my day bro, thank you very much :) @Simon LG